# Spring Boot + Jersey type filter - Bad request 400 for service Consumes MULTIPART_FORM_DATA

Tags: spring-boot, file-upload, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, servlet-filters

I'm using Spring boot v1.5.10 + Jersey v2.25.1, configured jersey as filter to access static folder files. I'm getting HTTP response 400 Bad Request for a service consuming `MULTIPART_FORM_DATA`.

Props to configure Jersey as filter.

```
spring.jersey.type=filter
```

If I remove above property i.e., using Jersey as Servlet, the service is working, but I'm not able to access static folder.

Here is the controller,

```
@POST
@Path("/save")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ResponseBean save(
        @FormDataParam("fileToUpload") InputStream file,
        @FormDataParam("fileToUpload") FormDataContentDisposition fileDisposition,
        @FormDataParam("fromData") FormDataDto data) {
    // stuff
}
```

**EDIT:**

GitHub link https://github.com/sundarabalajijk/boot-jersey

When you start the app, `spring.jersey.type=filter`

http://localhost:8080/ (works)

http://localhost:8080/hello.html (works)

http://localhost:8080/save (not working) - used postman.

When `spring.jersey.type=servlet`

http://localhost:8080/ (works)

http://localhost:8080/hello.html (not working)

http://localhost:8080/save (works)

[image: Postman request]

Comment: @Paul Samsotha - please check the GitHub link and requests. The http://localhost:8080/save (works) when spring.jersey.type=servlet

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After some research and finding related issues<sup>1</sup>, it seems that Spring's [`HiddenHttpMethodFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/HiddenHttpMethodFilter.html) reads the input stream, which leaves it empty for any other filters further down the filter chain. This is why we are getting a Bad Request in the Jersey filter; because the entity stream is empty. Here is the note from the Javadoc

> NOTE: This filter needs to run after multipart processing in case of a multipart POST request, due to its inherent need for checking a POST body parameter.

So what we need to do is configure the Jersey filter to be called before this Spring filter<sup>2</sup>. Based on the [Spring Boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jersey), there is a property we can use to easily configure the order of this filter.

```
spring.jersey.filter.order
```

Doing a [Github search](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=HiddenHttpMethodFilter&type=) in the Spring Boot repo for the `HiddenHttpMethodFilter`, we can see the subclass that is used [OrderedHiddenHttpMethodFilter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/d3c34ee3d1bfd3db4a98678c524e145ef9bca51c/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/filter/OrderedHiddenHttpMethodFilter.java), where the order is set to `-10000`. So we want to set the order of our Jersey filter to less than that (higher precedence). So we can set the following value

```
spring.jersey.filter.order=-100000
```

If you test it now, it should now work.

One more thing we need to fix is the order of the Spring `RequestContextFilter`. This is originally configured to be ordered to be called right before the Jersey filter. When we set the order configuration above for the Jersey filter, the `RequestContextFilter` stays where it was originally at. So we need to change this. We can do this just by adding a bean to override the original one and set the order.

```
@Bean
public RequestContextFilter requestContextFilter() {
    OrderedRequestContextFilter filter = new OrderedRequestContextFilter();
    filter.setOrder(-100001);
    return filter;
}
```

Now if we check the logs on startup, we should see the filer ordering we want.

```
Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
Mapping filter: 'jerseyFilter' to urls: [/*]
Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
```

---

#### Aside

The reason you need to configure Jersey as a filter in your case is because of the static content. If you don't configure the root path for the Jersey app, then it defaults to `/*`, which will hog up all requests, included those to the static content. So Jersey will throw 404 errors when requests are made for the static content. We configure Jersey as a filter and tell it to forward request that it cannot find.

If we were to just configure the root path for Jersey, then we would not need to worry about this problem with the static content, and we would be able to just leave Jersey configured as a servlet by default.

To change the base path for the Jersey app, we can either add the `@ApplicatuonPath` annotation to our `ResourceConfig` or we can use the property `spring.jersey.application-path`

```
@Component
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    ...
}
```

or in your `application.properties`

```
spring.jersey.application-path=/api
```

---

#### See also

- [File upload along with other object in Jersey restful web service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27614403/2587435). This has some information on how you can accept JSON as a body part in the multipart request.

---

#### Footnotes

<sub>1. Some issues to look at [ [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33846197/2587435), [2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5676#issuecomment-209421669) ]</sub>
<sub>2. See [Change order of RequestContextFilter in the filter chain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50428067/2587435)</sub>

Comment: This is a great explanation of the problem, but the solution of applying the Jersey filter at such an early order means it runs before Spring Security.

Comment: @AdrianBaker Yea, I wasn't using Spring Security, so I didn't take that into consideration. But it's good information for others.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the accepted answer is not up to date anymore. With Spring Boot 2 I did not have such problems. There was one issue though. I had a custom filter which was calling `getParameterMap` on the request object. Apparently `getParameterMap` implicitly reads the input stream of the request which then gets closed afterwards so that no other code can read the request body anymore.

Strangely with the setting `spring.jersey.type=servlet` I could get the request body even though `getParameterMap` was called beforehand, so I guess the implementation of `ServletRequest` is different depending on what you have configured for `spring.jersey.type`.