# Change order of RequestContextFilter in the filter chain

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using Jersey with Spring Boot and need to configure Jersey to run as a Servlet Filter. The problem with this is that with Multipart we get a 400 Bad Request for all requests. Further research shows that the [`HiddenHttpMethodFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/HiddenHttpMethodFilter.html) is the problem, as it read the request parameters, causing the request stream to be read, leaving nothing left for Jersey.

To fix this problem, I'm doing what's stated in the Javadoc of the `HiddenHttpMethodFilter`: configuring the Jersey filter to run before this filter.

> NOTE: This filter needs to run after multipart processing in case of a multipart POST request, due to its inherent need for checking a POST body parameter.

To configure the order of the Jersey filter, I'm using the Spring Boot property

```
spring.jersey.filter.order=-100000
```

This works. Below are the before and after logs of the filter chain order

Before

```
Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
Mapping filter: 'jerseyFilter' to urls: [/*]
```

After

```
Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
Mapping filter: 'jerseyFilter' to urls: [/*]
Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
```

So you can see the `jerseyFilter` is reordered correctly. But the `requestContextFilter` needs to be performed before the `jerseyFilter`. I was looking the the source for [`JerseyAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.10.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jersey/JerseyAutoConfiguration.java#L136), and it shows that the `requestContextFilter` order is set to `-1` of the Jersey filter configuration. But this doesn't seem to be what is happening

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public FilterRegistrationBean<RequestContextFilter> requestContextFilter() {
    FilterRegistrationBean<RequestContextFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    registration.setFilter(new RequestContextFilter());
    registration.setOrder(this.jersey.getFilter().getOrder() - 1);
    registration.setName("requestContextFilter");
    return registration;
}
```

On further investigation, I discovered that all the filters listed above have an `Ordered` subclass, which I assume is what's being registered. For instance, there is a `OrderedRequestContextFilter`, for which the order is set to `-105`.  And if I set the `DEBUG` logging, I can see that this is still the case, even when I set the Jersey filter order property

```
'characterEncodingFilter'; order=-2147483648,
'hiddenHttpMethodFilter'; order=-10000,
'httpPutFormContentFilter'; order=-9900,
'requestContextFilter'; order=-105,
```

So basically, I'm just trying to figure out what is the correct way to change the filter order for the `RequestContextFilter`, so that it performs right before the Jersey filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So in the [`WebMvcAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.0.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java), I found

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean({ RequestContextListener.class,
        RequestContextFilter.class })
public static RequestContextFilter requestContextFilter() {
    return new OrderedRequestContextFilter();
}
```

So I tried to add the same bean and set the order on the `OrderedRequestContextFilter`.

```
@Bean
public RequestContextFilter requestContextFilter() {
    OrderedRequestContextFilter filter = new OrderedRequestContextFilter();
    filter.setOrder(-100001);
    return filter;
}
```

This worked and I got the result I wanted; The `RequestContextFilter` is ordered right before the Jersey filter.

```
Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
Mapping filter: 'jerseyFilter' to urls: [/*]
Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
```

Comment: Spent like 5 hours on debugging and trying to find why input stream is drained before it gets ti jersey.Got the same conclusion.